# Node.Js WebPack Error when Using Dependency Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out why the `dependOn` WebPack property is failing when using multiple dependencies.

If I have an entry point as :

`./src/EntryA.js`

```
let LibraryA = require("./library/LibraryA.js");
let LibraryB = require("./library/LibraryB.js");

class EntryA {
    constructor() {
        console.log("EntryA");
        let libraryA = new LibraryA();
        let libraryB = new LibraryB();
    }
}

module.exports = EntryA;
```

With it's two dependencies as :

`./src/library/LibraryA.js`

```
class LibraryA {
    constructor() { console.log("LibraryA"); }
}

module.exports = LibraryA;
```

`./src/library/LibraryB.js`

```
class LibraryB {
    constructor() { console.log("LibraryB"); }
}

module.exports = LibraryB;
```

Then WebPack seems to have no problem creating the bundle with this config :

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    EntryA: {
        import: "./src/EntryA.js"
    }
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].min.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bundle"),
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: "[name]",
  },
  target: "web",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

This is fine but when the single bundle becomes too big and I want to split out the dependencies I run into problems, like with this updated config :

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    EntryA: {
        import: "./src/EntryA.js",
        dependOn: ["LibraryA", "LibraryB"]
    },
    LibraryA: "./src/library/LibraryA.js",
    LibraryB: "./src/library/LibraryB.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].min.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "bundle"),
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: "[name]",
  },
  target: "web",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

It looks like it's working because I still get the three bundles I am expecting

```
./bundle/LibraryA.min.js
./bundle/LibraryB.min.js
./bundle/EntryA.min.js
```

But trying to run them in the HTML file no longer works (without splitting the dependencies it did work) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./bundle/LibraryA.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle/LibraryB.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle/EntryA.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.onload = () => { const entryA = new EntryA(); }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the errors :

```
Uncaught TypeError: o[r] is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: EntryA is not a constructor
```

Comment: What version of Webpack you are using?

Comment: I'm using Webpack 5.88.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get this to work was to change all of the modules to use `import` instead of `require` and then the three bundles seem to play nice with each other.

I don't fully know why this fixes it but the dependencies seem to not like using `require`